# Should I handle this using multicast + broadcast, multicast only, or with multicast + IPv6?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, ipv6, multicast

So I have this situation in which I need to collect information from a remote computer over a long-range and possibly somewhat unreliable WiFi connection via a TCP socket (ensuring no information is lost is far more important than speed), and then rebroadcast it on the "reliable" end to other listeners via a multicast. This remote computer is a moving target, so simply tuning everything for a good range of sight is not possible. I've created a diagram below.

This remote computer isn't very powerful, so having all listeners connect to it via TCP sockets is not desirable, as it is already somewhat restricted in its available resources.

It is also desirable, however, for this remote computer to be able to be "discoverable" when someone connects to its WiFi network. As far as I understand, this is usually accomplished with periodic UDP broadcasts.

Now my issue is; how should I be doing this from a network perspective? From what I understand, UDP broadcasts typically are not supposed to cross out of their LAN, which in this case would only be the 10.0.1.0/8 subnet... meaning the "relay device" behind the router would be unable to see it. Apparently, if you have a router that allows for complex configuration (such as one running DD-WRT/Tomato) then you can force this behaviour across the respective VLANs...  which is apparently not a good idea? I would assume that would screw up the DHCP too, allowing DHCP requests from clients on the router to be accidentally served by the long-range WiFi network.

My other option is to do the "service discovery" via multicasting over a set port and multicast address all the clients know to listen on (i.e. 224.239.74.2:45454), because multicasts are supposed to be able to cross LANs (after simple configuration I suppose).

In regard to multicasting though, I've been lead to understand that doing it over WiFi is generally a bad idea (not sure why though). Some of the monitoring devices may be connected over WiFi broadcasted from the intermediary router. I could change it such that all monitoring devices connect to the relay via TCP, but that does not seem scalable in the event that the relay is either relatively weak (i.e. another embedded computer), or if an unprecedented number of monitoring devices are added to the network in the future.

Because this network is completely closed (not connected to the internet), I've been wondering if IPv6 could be a solution. I don't know much about IPv6 aside from a ridiculous number of addresses and essentially no more subnetting. I've read online that multicasting is inherent to the protocol (unlike optional with IPv4), which would lead me to believe that whatever issue there is with multicasting over IPv4 on WiFi has been resolved. This is also assuming that all modern equipment is essentially "IPv6 ready".

Could someone please advise me on what I should do from here? I'm not very experienced in this stuff and everything I've written is speculative.

[image: Wow, so network!]

Comment: I think you need [ØMQ](http://zeromq.org/); in particular see [chapter 8 of their guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Chapter-A-Framework-for-Distributed-Computing) for a possible solution. Don't try to do multicast over Wi-Fi, as it slows down all stations to the lowest bitrate and kills every station's performance.

Comment: Or, [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/).  Multicast/broadcast should be relegated for discovery purposes due to lack of congestion control and limited bandwidth available on radio networks.